# What is the best data type for storing pictures in the ActiveRecord (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best Data Type for storing pictures in rails? I am currently creating my models using the ActiveRecord and I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 4):

Although you can store files in the database as a Binary Big Objects (blobs), its not really the best solution as increases the size of the database which causes [performance problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database), makes backups and replication slower and generally makes the lives of anybody maintaining the app miserable.

A better approach taken by [ActiveStorage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) is to store files on disk and just paths to the file (strings) in the database. This lets you use a local disk (on your server or development box) or cloud based services like Amazon S3, Google Cloud and Microsoft Azure for performance and scalability.

This is the migration created by `rails active_storage:install`:

```
class CreateActiveStorageTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :active_storage_blobs do |t|
      t.string   :key,        null: false
      t.string   :filename,   null: false
      t.string   :content_type
      t.text     :metadata
      t.bigint   :byte_size,  null: false
      t.string   :checksum,   null: false
      t.datetime :created_at, null: false

      t.index [ :key ], unique: true
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

The name blob here has nothing to do with database binary columns - rather a ActiveStorage::Blob is:

> ... a record that contains the metadata about a file and a key for where that file resides on the service.

As you can see it uses a variety of column types (mainly strings) to store key information about the file so that it can be retrieved as well as some nice extra metadata.